# Kendo Grid reorder get error DOM Exception: NOT_FOUND_ERR (8)

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid that allow user add in new row and beside of the grid is two button(up and down)for reorder the sequence of row inside. After that user will need to click on save button to save the data into server.

The reorder work fine before the save, after click save and want to reorder the row again, it will get error **DOM Exception: NOT_FOUND_ERR (8)**. I really have no idea how to solve this.

This is my code for the reorder:

```
    $("#btnMoveUp").on("click", function (e) {
    var grid = $("#field-grid").data("kendoGrid");
    var select = grid.select();
    var selectedItem = select.closest("tr");
    if (selectedItem.length > 0) {
        var selectedUid = selectedItem.attr("data-uid");
        var itemIndex = selectedItem.index();
        var dataItem = grid.dataItem(selectedItem);

        var newIndex = itemIndex - 1;
        var content = $(".k-grid-content");
        var offset = selectedItem.offset().top;

        if (newIndex <= 0) {
            newIndex = 0;
        }

        grid.dataSource.remove(dataItem);
        grid.dataSource.insert(newIndex, dataItem);

        grid.select("[data-uid=" + selectedUid + "]");

        //content.scrollTop(offset);
    } else {
        alert("Please select the row to change the sequence of field.");
    }
});

$("#btnMoveDown").on("click", function (e) {
    var grid = $("#field-grid").data("kendoGrid");
    var select = grid.select();
    var selectedItem = select.closest("tr");
    if (selectedItem.length > 0) {
        var selectedUid = selectedItem.attr("data-uid");
        var itemIndex = selectedItem.index();
        var dataItem = grid.dataItem(selectedItem);

        var newIndex = itemIndex + 1;
        var content = $(".k-grid-content");

        var offset = selectedItem.offset().top;

        if (newIndex < grid.dataSource.view().length) {
            grid.dataSource.remove(dataItem);
            grid.dataSource.insert(newIndex, dataItem);

            grid.select("[data-uid=" + selectedUid + "]");

            //content.scrollTop(offset);
        }

    } else {
        alert("Please select the row to change the sequence of field.");
    }
});
```

My code for grid declaration:

```
        var fieldGrid = $("#field-grid").kendoGrid({
        height: 320,
        dataSource: fieldDataSource,
        selectable: "row",
        scrollable: true,
        toolbar: [{
            template: ...
        }],
        columns: [...],
        editable: { mode: "inline", "createAt": "bottom", confirmation: false }            
    }).data("kendoGrid");
```

Comment: Do you perhaps have your grid declareation?  (It would help to see the grid code).  Are you using inline editing?

Comment: @gardarvalur yes..i'm using inline editing..